# how to sum price in array per user? in javascript 2d arry

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

Hi I have below json and try to get sum of price per each user.
for example, KYLE1 : 300.6, KYLE2: 1188.6.
but failed to seperate it from each.. please help

is there a way to stop for loop between users?

```
    var json = [
    {
    "name" : " KYLE 1",
    "addr" : " SEOUL",
    "buyproducts" : [ {
        "prodname": "prod1", "price": 100.2, "date": "2003-01-04"},{
        "prodname": "prod2", "price": 100.2, "date": "2003-06-04"},{
        "prodname": "prod3", "price": 100.2, "date": "2003-08-04"}
    ]},
    {
    "name" : " KYLE 2",
    "addr" : " SEOUL",
    "buyproducts" : [ {
        "prodname": "prod4", "price": 13.2, "date": "2003-03-04"},{
        "prodname": "prod5", "price": 633.2, "date": "2003-07-04"},{
        "prodname": "prod6", "price": 542.2, "date": "2003-01-04"}
    ]},
    {
    "name" : " KYLE 3",
    "addr" : " SEOUL",
    "buyproducts" : [ {
        "prodname": "prod1", "price": 75.2, "date": "2003-01-04"},{
        "prodname": "prod2", "price": 35.2, "date": "2004-07-04"},{
        "prodname": "prod3", "price": 52.2, "date": "2005-02-04"}
    ]}
    ]


--------------------------------


    var totalCost = function(arr){
        var array = [];
        var priceSum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

            for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].buyproducts.length; j++){
                priceSum += arr[i].buyproducts[j].price;
            } array.push(priceSum)
            console.log(arr[i].name + ": " + priceSum)
        }
    }

    totalCost(json);
```

Comment: You need a new `priceSum` variable for each user ... not one variable for all users. Or you need to reset it each iteration of the outer loop

Comment: @charlietfl Hi, Thanks for the comment, If I set the priceSum to each user, I think If I do not know the number of user then, I think that won't works., in case of 2 option, can you let me know how to use reset iteration?

Comment: Move `var priceSum = 0;` inside the outer loop. That will give you a `priceSum ` for each user. If you need a total for all users that would be different and does not appear to be what you are asking

Comment: @charlietfl It looks it shows same result even I move priceSum above from var total
KYLE 1: 300.6
 KYLE 2: 1489.2
 KYLE 3: 1651.8000000000002
 KYLE 4: 2612.3999999999996

Comment: @charlietfl should I change something about   
=> console.log(arr[i].name + ": " + priceSum) ??

Comment: question: could `json` have more than one 'KILE 1' for example? I mean, could it have several items with the same name?

Comment: @Scaramouche, can have a same name but at this moment no, cuz nothing can identify the identity of each person.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
var json = [
  {
    name: " KYLE 1",
    addr: " SEOUL",
    buyproducts: [
      {
        prodname: "prod1",
        price: 100.2,
        date: "2003-01-04"
      },
      {
        prodname: "prod2",
        price: 100.2,
        date: "2003-06-04"
      },
      {
        prodname: "prod3",
        price: 100.2,
        date: "2003-08-04"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: " KYLE 2",
    addr: " SEOUL",
    buyproducts: [
      {
        prodname: "prod4",
        price: 13.2,
        date: "2003-03-04"
      },
      {
        prodname: "prod5",
        price: 633.2,
        date: "2003-07-04"
      },
      {
        prodname: "prod6",
        price: 542.2,
        date: "2003-01-04"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: " KYLE 3",
    addr: " SEOUL",
    buyproducts: [
      {
        prodname: "prod1",
        price: 75.2,
        date: "2003-01-04"
      },
      {
        prodname: "prod2",
        price: 35.2,
        date: "2004-07-04"
      },
      {
        prodname: "prod3",
        price: 52.2,
        date: "2005-02-04"
      }
    ]
  }
];

let sumArray = {};

for (const user of json) {
  sumArray[user.name] = user.buyproducts.reduce(
    (accu, value) => (accu + value.price),
    0
  );
}

console.log(sumArray);
```